# Django class-based view to return HttpResponse such as HttpResponseBadRequest

Tags: django

I have a custom Django view class that inherits from the generic `DetailView`.

The generic `DetailView` class sequentially calls its methods `get_queryset`, `get_object`, and others to generate an object to pass for a Django template.

Moreover, the generic `DetailView` class raises `Http404` exception within these methods to deal with erroneous situations [#](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/detail.py#L54).

```
except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                  {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
```

What I am trying to do is simple: I want to return other HTTP status codes to the client if an error is found within these methods. However, because `Http404` is the only Django `HttpResponse` that has a form of exception, it seems like this cannot be achieved easily.

Because `HttpResponse` is not an exception, I have to return it instead of raising it. Therefore, the customized method becomes the following form.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
   ...
   try:
      # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
      obj = queryset.get()
   except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
      return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad request.")
```

However, above code does not send `HttpResponseBadRequest` to the client. Instead, it returns `HttpResponseBadRequest` as an object for a Django template. The client gets 200 status code with an invalid object for the template.

The only possible solution to think is writing some object-checking code within the Django template. However, I wonder if there is any better way to deal with this problem.

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: I am using the latest version, 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django 3.2 we now have an exception [`BadRequest` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/exceptions/#badrequest) which will be turned into a `HttpResponseBadRequest` internally when caught, so you can try catching `Http404` and raising `BadRequest` instead:

```
from django.core.exceptions import BadRequest


class MyView(SomeGenericView):
    ...
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            return super().get_object(queryset=queryset)
        except Http404 as e:
            # raise BadRequest("Bad request.") from e
            raise BadRequest("Bad request.")
```

For some previous version we can try to catch the exception at the `dispatch` method and return the appropriate response there:

```
class MyView(SomeGenericView):
    ...
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad request.")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Becuase I also want to use some other HTTP status codes, I think I can take advantage of both methods.

Comment: @J.Choi note that there is also the [`PermissionDenied`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/exceptions/#permissiondenied) exception which turns into a 403 response status code

Comment: Just for a note to others who try to do the same thing: `raise Exception("Message.")` will create a 500 response, however, `handler500` does not take an exception parameter [\[djangoticket\]](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4007). Therefore, using `raise Exception()` for both 500 code and custom message seems impossible.